# UnknownError: THE MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM SOURCE IS REQUIRED (PHP 5.3)

Tags: cakephp-2.3, php-5.6

I am trying to run website on local system. I got the following error:

> UnknownError: THE MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM SOURCE IS REQUIRED (PHP 5.3)

I am using `cakephp2.5` framework, `php5.6` and OS is `ubuntu16`. How to resolve this error ? Please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by using **MCRYPT_RAND**.